# Ruby shorter way for ?: on binary search

Tags: ruby

When applying binary search, I could write the following code in C++:

```
lb = 0, ub = N // answer range is [lb, ub)  
(ok(lb + ub >> 1) ? lb : ub) = lb + ub >> 1
```

However, it seems like this notation doesn't compile in Ruby, so the best way I could think of is something like:

```
ok(lb + ub >> 1) ? lb = lb + ub >> 1 : ub = lb + ub >> 1
```

which is acceptable, but I hope there could be some way more beautiful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: "I hope there could be some way more beautiful." Isn't that primarily opinion based?  Please say what you mean by that.

Comment: Is the first one really a valid expression in C? I can't imagine result of the ternary being a valid left part.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - It's valid in C++.  Though "valid" != "good"...

Comment: By beautiful, I meant less repetitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple extraction of the repetitive part should do the trick, no?

```
a = lb + ub >> 1
ok(a) ? lb = a : ub = a
```

Comment: Guess it couldn't be improved more. Thank you.